# SQL Select replace embedded space with a character, and remove characters after -

Tags: sql, select, replace, case

I am retreiving information from a BES (Blackberry Enterprise Server).  I need to change the Display Name field from the BES to a name.name format.

The Display name comes across as First Last and possible First Last-EXT for example.  I need to drop the dash after any last name with it, and also add a . between first and last.

I have tried using REPLACE to add the .
And I have tried CASE to remove the - and everthing after it.  But how can I combine into one statement to do both?

```
,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[DisplayName])>0 THEN LEFT([DisplayName], CHARINDEX('-',[DisplayName])-1) ELSE [DisplayName] END

,REPLACE([DisplayName], ' ','.') AS 'Display Name'
```

edit : added code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

you have done all the work.

in your case statement you return the DisplayName that you want (removing '-' from lastname and every character following '-') so use that output and apply replace to replace your blank space to '.'

```
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[DisplayName])>0 
      THEN REPLACE(LEFT([DisplayName], CHARINDEX('-',[DisplayName])-1), ' ','.') 
      ELSE REPLACE([DisplayName], ' ','.') 
 END
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!